# probabilities of event happening at least twice

Tags: probability

I've been busy with a few probabilities and the ones that seem to be most painful for me to wrap my head around are the ones that have a probability of going to infinity like this one.

Independent experiments are happening until event A has happened twice. What is the probability that you will need no more than 7 experiments, if probability for event A to happen is 0.34

now what i understand is:

- A has to happen twice or more
- experiment number must be no more than 7

so I've devised a solution:

$C^2_7(0.34)^2(0.66)^5$

however as much as i understand my solution was only correct if we needed event A to happen exactly twice, so how do i fix my way of thought?

Comment: It is easier to count the probability that it does not happen or happen only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event that you need is complementary to the event that $A$ does not occur at all in seven trials *or* that $A$ happens exactly once in seven trials.

The probability of that is $\displaystyle 0.66^7 + \binom{7}{1}(0.66^6)(0.34)$

and your required probabilty is one minus that, or $\approx 0.748$.

Comment: seems to be correct, should've taken it the other way around.

Comment: yes, considering the complementary event is often easier in questions worded "at least" and so forth.